# 2 while read loops?

Tags: bash, while-loop

So the object of the script I'm making is to compare files from two while read lists that have file path names in them...

```
while read compareFile <&3; do     
 if [[ ! $server =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
  continue
 fi   
    echo "Comparing file - $compareFile"
 if diff "$compareFile" _(other file from loop?_) >/dev/null ; then
    echo Same
 else
     echo Different
 fi   
 done 3</infanass/dev/admin/filestoCompare.txt
```

**I need to be able to compare files from two different lists at the same time through two while read loops... Is this even possible?**

Answer (score 4):

I think I would restructure that along these lines:

```
while true
do
   read -u3 line1 || break
   read -u4 line2 || break

   # do whatever...
done 3< file1 4< file2
```

That uses a single loop, and will exit that loop when end of file is reached on either input file. The logic would be a little more complicated if you want to read both files entirely, even if one ends early...

Answer (score 1):

Not really understand what you want achieve, but the next:

```
while read -r file1 file2
do
    echo diff "$file1" "$file2"
done < <(paste <(grep . list1.txt) <(grep . list2.txt))
```

where the `list1.txt` contains:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt

file3.txt

file4.txt
file5.txt
```

and the `list2.txt` contains:

```
another1.txt

another2.txt
another3.txt
another4.txt

another5.txt
```

produces the next output:

```
diff file1.txt another1.txt
diff file2.txt another2.txt
diff file3.txt another3.txt
diff file4.txt another4.txt
diff file5.txt another5.txt
```

Remove the `echo` before the `diff` if you satisfied.

Comment: Much safer if you use `IFS=$'\t' read -r file1 file2`; that way non-tab whitespace inside the columns won't break the code. (Even better than that, of course, would be a solution that didn't treat any characters but newlines as special).

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly...yes. Here's an example of looping through two files in lock-step

```
exec 3<filelist1.txt
exec 4<filelist2.txt
while read -r file1 <&3 && read -r file2 <&4; do echo ${file1}","${file2}; done
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

Comment: `echo "$file1,$file2"` would be more correct -- right now if you have a line containing, say, `hello * world`, the `*` would be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read newfile <&3; do   
 if [[ ! $newfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
 #
 while read oldfile <&3; do   
 if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
    echo Comparing "$newfile" with "$oldfile"
    #
    if diff "$newfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
      echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
    else
        echo The files compared are different.
        #
    fi    
  done 3</home/u0146121/test/oldfiles.txt
 done 3</home/u0146121/test/newfiles.txt
```